# multiplication of Hilbert Schmidt operators and bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Suppose $T_1,T_2 \in B(H)$,where $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. $S\in \mathcal{HS}(H)$,$\mathcal{HS}(H)$ is the set of Hilbert Schmidt operators on $H$.

Does there exist nonzero operators $T_3,T_4 \in B(H)$ such that $T_1T_3ST_4T_2=\alpha S$,where $\alpha$ is a nonzero complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $T_3$ or $T_4$ being the zero operator, we have $T_1T_3ST_4T_2=0=0S$.

If you want $\alpha\neq0$, then the answer is no.  If either $T_1$ or $T_2$ is rank one, then $T_1T_3ST_4T_2$ will be rank one (or zero).  But $\alpha S$ will have the same rank as $S$, which can be any natural number, or infinite.

Comment: If $S$ is a finte rank projection,what about the conclusion?

Comment: I want to take $T_3,T_4$ be the inverse element of $T1,T2$,so I asked the question of the criterion of invertibility of bounded operators